# F# How to tokenise user input: separating numbers, units, words?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I am fairly new to F#, but have spent the last few weeks reading reference materials. I wish to process a user-supplied input string, identifying and separating the constituent elements. For example, for this input:

> XYZ Hotel: 6 nights at 220EUR / night
>   plus 17.5% tax

the output should resemble something like a list of tuples:

> [ ("XYZ", Word);   ("Hotel:", Word);
>   ("6", Number);   ("nights", Word);
>   ("at", Operator);   ("220", Number);
>   ("EUR", CurrencyCode);   ("/",
>   Operator);   ("night", Word);
>   ("plus", Operator);   ("17.5",
>   Number);   ("%", PerCent);   ("tax",
>   Word) ]

Since I'm dealing with user input, it could be anything. Thus, expecting users to comply with a grammar is out of the question. I want to identify the numbers (could be integers, floats, negative...), the units of measure (optional, but could include SI or Imperial physical units, currency codes, counts such as "night/s" in my example), mathematical operators (as math symbols or as words including "at" "per", "of", "discount", etc), and all other words.

I have the impression that I should use active pattern matching -- is that correct? -- but I'm not exactly sure how to start. Any pointers to appropriate reference material or similar examples would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put together an example using the [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) library. The example is not robust at all but it gives a pretty good picture of how to use FParsec.

```
type Element =
| Word of string
| Number of string
| Operator of string
| CurrencyCode of string
| PerCent  of string    

let parsePerCent state =
    (parse {
        let! r = pstring "%"
        return PerCent r
    }) state

let currencyCodes = [|
    pstring "EUR"
|]

let parseCurrencyCode state =
    (parse {
        let! r = choice currencyCodes
        return CurrencyCode r
    }) state

let operators = [|
    pstring "at"
    pstring "/"
|]

let parseOperator state =
    (parse {
        let! r = choice operators
        return Operator r
    }) state

let parseNumber state =
    (parse {
        let! e1 = many1Chars digit
        let! r = opt (pchar '.')
        let! e2 = manyChars digit
        return Number (e1 + (if r.IsSome then "." else "") + e2)
    }) state

let parseWord state =
    (parse {
        let! r = many1Chars (letter <|> pchar ':')
        return Word r
    }) state

let elements = [| 
    parseOperator
    parseCurrencyCode
    parseWord
    parseNumber 
    parsePerCent
|]

let parseElement state =
    (parse {
        do! spaces
        let! r = choice elements
        do! spaces
        return r
    }) state

let parseElements state =
    manyTill parseElement eof state

let parse (input:string) =
    let result = run parseElements input 
    match result with
    | Success (v, _, _) -> v
    | Failure (m, _, _) -> failwith m
```

Comment: That's a comprehensive response.  Are you saying that FParsec is a good solution, even though I'm dealing with free format text -- not a strict grammar?

Comment: @David - Exactly, FParsec was written to be a text parsing tool and it is a flexible one at that.

Comment: I ran your example and I'm most impressed. Now I need to read up the documentation for FParsec, so that I can intelligently modify this, as needed.

Comment: @David - Hey, that's great. I've been able to do some fantastic work with FParsec and I don't think I could recommend it any more highly. Take note that some of the API can be a bit obtuse so make sure you keep that documentation open. :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is just a lexer. A good alternative to FSParsec would be FSLex. (Good intro tutorial, albiet somewhat dated, can be found on my old blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/01/18/fslex-sample.aspx).)  Using FSLex you can take your input text:

```
XYZ Hotel: 6 nights at 220EUR / night plus 17.5% tax
```

And get it properly tokenized into something like:

```
 [ Word("XYZ"); Hotel; Int(6); Word("nights"); Word("at"); Int(220); EUR; ... ]
```

The next step, once you have an List of tokens, is to do some form of pattern matching / analysis to extract semantic information (which I assume is what you are really after). With the normalized token stream, it should be as simple as:

```
let rec processTokenList tokens = 
    match tokens with
    | Float(x) :: Keyword("EUR") :: rest  -> // Dollar amount x
    | Word(x) :: Keyword("Hotel") :: rest -> // Hotel x
    | hd :: rest -> // Couldn't find anything interesting...
                    processTokenList rest
```

That should at least get you started. But note that as your input gets more 'formal', so will the usefulness of your lexing. (And if you only accept a very specific input, then you can use a proper parser and be done with it!)