# How to extract data from F# list

Tags: f#, fparsec

Following up [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653820/f-how-to-tokenise-user-input-separating-numbers-units-words), I'm slowly getting the hang of FParsec (though I do find it particularly hard to grok).

My next newbie F# question is, how do I extract data from the list the parser creates?

For example, I loaded the sample code from the previous question into a module called Parser.fs, and added a very simple unit test in a separate module (with the appropriate references). I'm using XUnit:

```
open Xunit

[<Fact>]
let Parse_1_ShouldReturnListContaining1 () =
    let interim = Parser.parse("1")
    Assert.False(List.isEmpty(interim))

    let head = interim.Head // I realise that I have only one item in the list this time
    Assert.Equal("1", ???)
```

Interactively, when I execute **parse "1"** the response is:

```
val it : Element list = [Number "1"]
```

and by tweaking the list of valid operators, I can run **parse "1+1"** to get:

```
val it : Element list = [Number "1"; Operator "+"; Number "1"]
```

What do I need to put in place of my **???** in the snippet above? And how do I check that it is a Number, rather than an Operator, etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F# types (including lists) implement structural equality. This means that if you compare two lists that contain some F# types using `=`, it will return true when the types have the same length and contain elements with the same properties.

Assuming that the `Element` type is a discriminated union defined in F# (and is not an object type), you should be able to write just:

```
Assert.Equal(interim, [Number "1"; Operator "+"; Number "1"])
```

If you wanted to implement the equality yourself, then you could use pattern matching;

```
let expected = [Number "1"]
match interim, expected with
| Number a, Number b when a = b -> true
| _ -> false
```